# How to update a component in a ES6 map function in React stateless component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component that is a modal. Inside I am doing a map on a array to render picture. I would like to add a div on the picture of one picture when clicking on it. However, it appears that the UI is not updated inside of the map even when using useState. Any idea on how to solve the issue?

Here is the code (I removed Style and things that were not important):

```
const CreateBoardModal = ({ closeModal, isModalOpen, searchResults, ...props }) => {
  Modal.setAppElement('body')
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
  const [searchResultsAdded, setSearchResultAdded] = useState({})

  const addMovie = (movieId) => {
    if (movies.includes(movieId)) {
      console.log("Already in the list")
    } else {
      console.log("Added to the list!")
      var movies_temp = movies
      movies_temp.push(movieId)
      setMovies(movies_temp)
    }
    var searchMoviesTemp = searchResultsAdded
    searchMoviesTemp[movieId] = true
    setSearchResultAdded(searchMoviesTemp)
    console.log(searchResultsAdded) //Here everything is updated as expected
  }

  return (
    <Modal
      isOpen={isModalOpen}
      onRequestClose={closeModal}
    >
        <div>
          {searchResults.length > 0 &&
            searchResults.map((movie, index) => {
              return (
                <div style={{ margin: 10 }} onClick={() => addMovie(movie.id)}>
                  <Movie
                    title={movie.original_title}
                    voteAverage={movie.vote_average}
                    posterPath={movie.poster_path}
                  ></Movie>
                  {searchResultsAdded[movie.id] &&
                    <div>Added ✓</div> } {/*This is shown only when I hot reload the react app*/}
                </div>
              )
            })}
      </div>
    </Modal >
  )
}

export default CreateBoardModal;
```

Comment: You are mutating the state, try to do `const movies_temp = [...movies]`; And actually the same with your other state.

Comment: try spread syntax, i.e. ```setSearchResultAdded({movieId: true, ...searchResultAdded})```

Comment: @mymoto: the `movieId` looks like a dynamic value, spreading would rather need the `setSearchResultAdded({...searchResultAdded, [movieId]: true})`